# C++ format char with char?

Tags: c++, format

I am pretty sure that this has been answered somewhere but I cannot really find the answer(I am probably blind). However, I have this code:

```
TCHAR name[UNLEN + 1];
DWORD size = UNLEN + 1;

char path[250]; = "X:\\users\\HEREname\\Documents\\Games\\";
```

Note: `TCHAR` is simply a typedef for `char` and `DWORD` is typedef for `unsigned` int.

So I was wonder what the proper way is to format the `name` in the `path` so that "HEREname" gets replaced with the `name` char. I cannot really find out how to do this with strings either and dunno why I cannot find it.... :/

Thanks!

Comment: the extraneous `;` notwithstanding, you do it *functionally* using *code*. [snprintf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) would seem a good candidate to study.

Comment: You want to replace it in place or replace and copy?

Comment: `how to concatenate C++` <- Google!

Comment: You're still using TCHAR?! In 2017?!

Comment: thanks all haha and the `;` was of course a typo and @MrEricSir what is wrong with using TCHAR? Btw this code is from a tutorial so please do not blame me ://

Answer (score 1):

`TCHAR` **may** be a typedef for `char`, or it **may** be a typedef for `wchar_t` instead.  It depends on whether your project is configured for MBCS (`char`) or Unicode (`wchar_t`).  Since `path[]` is explicitly `char`, `name` should be using `char` to match, instead of `TCHAR`.  Otherwise, you have to perform a runtime conversion if `TCHAR` is `wchar_t`.

For what you are attempting, you can use a function like `snprint()` (or the `TCHAR` equivalent, `_sntprintf()`) or similar, eg:

```
char name[UNLEN + 1];
DWORD size = UNLEN + 1;

if (GetUserNameA(name, &size))
{
    char path[MAX_PATH] = {0};

    int len = snprintf(path, MAX_PATH, "X:\\users\\%s\\Documents\\Games\\", name);
    if ((len > 0) && (len < MAX_PATH))
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Or:

```
TCHAR name[UNLEN + 1];
DWORD size = UNLEN + 1;

if (GetUserName(name, &size))
{
    TCHAR path[MAX_PATH] = {0};

    int len = _sntprintf(path, MAX_PATH, _T("X:\\users\\%s\\Documents\\Games\\"), name);
    if ((len > 0) && (len < MAX_PATH))
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you really need to mix `TCHAR` and `char` (which I don't recommend):

```
#ifdef UNICODE
#define PRINTF_TSTR_FMT "%ls"
#else
#define PRINTF_TSTR_FMT "%s"
#endif

TCHAR name[UNLEN + 1];
DWORD size = UNLEN + 1;

if (GetUserName(name, &size))
{
    char path[MAX_PATH] = {0};

    int len = snprintf(path, MAX_PATH, "X:\\users\\" PRINTF_TSTR_FMT "\\Documents\\Games\\", name);
    if ((len > 0) && (len < MAX_PATH))
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

That being said, you really should not make assumptions about where Windows stores user profiles.  The location can differ on separate machines, and especially across different versions of Windows.  Use the Shell API instead to query system paths, eg:

```
TCHAR path[MAX_PATH] = {0};

if (SHGetFolderPath(NULL, CSIDL_MYDOCUMENTS, NULL, SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT, path) == S_OK)
{
    if (PathAppend(path, TEXT("Games")))
    {
        // use path as needed...
    }
}
```

Alternatively, on Vista and later:

```
PWSTR pDocsPath = NULL;

// or maybe even FOLDERID_Games...
if (SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_Documents, 0, NULL, &pPath) == S_OK)
{
    TCHAR path[MAX_PATH] = {0};

    bool bOK = (PathCombine(path, pDocsPath, TEXT("Games")) != NULL);
    CoTaskMemFree(pDocsPath);

    if (bOK)
    {
        // use path as needed...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of methods:

```
//Paths in C++ can all use '/', they don't need to have system-specific delimiters
std::string root = "X:/users/"
std::string user_name = /*...*/;
std::string path = "/Documents/Games/";

std::string final_path = root + user_name + path;
//TODO: Input sanitizing, to ensure no chance of rogue code

std::fstream file(final_path + file_name, /*...*/);
```

That's probably the simplest method.

This method is a little more performant:

```
std::stringstream path;
path << "X:/Users/";
path << user_name;
path << "/Documents/Games/";
path << file_name;

std::string final_path = path.str();
std::fstream file(final_path, /*...*/);
```

If you have a C++17 compliant compiler, this is vastly preferred:

```
std::filesystem::path path = "X:/users";
path /= user_name;
path /= "Documents";
path /= "Games";

std::fstream file(path / file_name, /*...*/);
```

Comment: You should add `std::ostringstream` to you list of examples.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I was actually trying to remember that one! I was drawing a blank. XD